# KVM: Is it possible to trap the ICEBP/INT1 instruction?

Tags: kvm

I am attempting to trap the [`ICEBP` / `INT1`](https://namazso.github.io/x86/html/INT_n_INTO_INT3_INT1.html) instruction in KVM. Is it possible to cause a guest exit for this instruction, e.g. using `KVM_SET_GUEST_DEBUG`?

### Background

I am working on a hypervisor for Windows and Linux that includes debugging support (single stepping and breakpoints). I am currently able to perform single stepping and breakpoints by using the appropriate combinations of `KVM_GUESTDBG_ENABLE`, `KVM_GUESTDBG_USE_SW_BP` and `KVM_GUESTDBG_SINGLESTEP` in `KVM_SET_GUEST_DEBUG`. I am using the well known `INT3` instruction for breakpoints.

The problem is that the Linux kernel uses the `INT3` instruction for its own purposes during kernel startup ([`int3_selftest`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.2/arch/x86/kernel/alternative.c#L1309)). This causes problems for anyone attempting to debug the Linux kernel. As an alternative I am attempting to use the `ICEBP` / `INT1` instruction for breakpoints: this instruction causes a #DB exception instead of a #BP exception, but one can differentiate between single stepping and `INT1` by looking at the instruction pointed by RIP or looking at the DR6 / BS bit.

This works on the Windows [`WHv*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/hypervisor-platform/hypervisor-platform) API. Unfortunately I am unable to make it work on KVM, because KVM never delivers the #DB exception for `INT1` to my hypervisor (i.e. it nevers delivers a `KVM_EXIT_DEBUG` for `INT1` and seems to skip the instruction). Is it possible to convince it to deliver the `KVM_EXIT_DEBUG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received a response from Sean Christopherson on the KVM mailing list. He states:

> #DBs from INT1, a.k.a. ICEBP, should be forwarded to userspace if KVM_GUESTDBG_USE_HW_BP is set.

https://lore.kernel.org/kvm/ZAZVCosmv+KXA8mO@google.com/T/#t